# How to print tokenized arabic text in python/nltk?

Tags: python, encoding, nltk, arabic

I'm doing the sentiment analysis for arabic language, I'm using python /nltk and the dream pie shell ,this problem occurs when I apply the function of tokenization , how to display these words ?

```
>>> import nltk
>>> sentence = "مصادمات عنيفه في"
>>> tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
>>> tokens
['\xd9\x85\xd8\xb5\xd8\xa7\xd8\xaf\xd9\x85\xd8\xa7\xd8\xaa', '\xd8\xb9\xd9\x86\xd9\x8a\xd9\x81\xd9\x87', '\xd9\x81\xd9\x8a']
```

Answer (score 1):

By printing tokens, you're printing the list and the `\x...` is the bytecode representation. If you want to print out the arabic form, just loop through the list and print the tokens one by one.

```
>>> import nltk
>>> sentence = "مصادمات عنيفه في"
>>> tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
>>> tokens
['\xd9\x85\xd8\xb5\xd8\xa7\xd8\xaf\xd9\x85\xd8\xa7\xd8\xaa', '\xd8\xb9\xd9\x86\xd9\x8a\xd9\x81\xd9\x87', '\xd9\x81\xd9\x8a']
>>> for i in tokens:
...     print i
... 
مصادمات
عنيفه
في
```